# mod rewrite 3 subdomains redirected to themselves (universal redirect)

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

Currently I am using: 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.test.example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://sub1.test.example.net/folder1/folder2/app/nodes/dir1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2.test.example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://sub2.test.example.net/folder1/folder2/app/nodes/dir1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub3.test.example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://sub3.test.example.net/folder1/folder2/app/nodes/dir1 [R,L]

I am trying to condense a universal rule for the 3 different env's to possible 2 lines, for ex:

Rewrite condition: sub1 OR sub2 Or sub3
Rewrite Rule: (sub1 OR sub2 Or sub3).example.net/folder1/folder2/app/nodes/dir1

I apologize for being a newbie, I have been reading the apache mod rewrite man pages for a couple of days but havent been able to crack it. Even a point in the right direction would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an [OR] flag after each condition if you only want to process the rule on specific subdomains but if you just want to match any subdomain you can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).test.example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%1.test.example.net/folder1/folder2/app/nodes/dir1 [R,L]
```

This would for example redirect http://sub777.test.example.net/?test to https://sub777.test.example.net/folder1/folder2/app/nodes/dir1?test